# EC2にてtomcatを使いjspを表示しようとすると404になる

Tags: amazon-ec2, tomcat, jsp

EC2にてtomcatを使いjspを表示しようとすると404になります。

tomcat 9.43
java　1.8.0_272

インバウンドルールのポート8080・80は追加してあります。
http://*****:8080にてtomcatは表示れます。
Apacheも動作確認済みです。

問題のhello.jspは
tomcat/webapps/sample/hello.jspにあります。

http://*****:8080/sample/hello.jspにて表示しようとしますが
404
JSP file [/sample/hello.jsp] not found
オリジンサーバーは、ターゲットリソースの現在の表現を見つけられなかったか、またはそれが存在することを開示するつもりはありません。
上記のエラーが出てしまいます。

Apache・tomcatの再起動を致しましたが解決しませんでした。
どなたかご教示いただけましたら幸いでございます。

Comment: デフォルト状態で"`JSP file [/sample/hello.jsp] not found`"と表示されるのは、 `webapp`ディレクトリ以下に`sample`ディレクトリが存在しない場合のようです(存在していれば`[/hello.jsp]`)。 **sample** のつづりを間違えてはいないでしょうか。